# Add dropbox webhook by code

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api

We're exploring dropbox api reference. Concretly, we're exploring webhook possibilities.

We're not quite to know how to specify a webhook url by code.

We are lokking for a way to add this webhook url avoiding user has to do it manually.

I hope I've explained so well.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to programmatically register a Dropbox webhook URI. We'll consider it a feature request.

Developers should register their webhook URI(s) manually via the [App Console](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/apps). Those webhook URIs will stay registered and will be used for all users connected to the app.